# How to write a test class for a Constructor?

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

In my Apex controller, I have a Constructor method which initializes two variables by querying custom objects using id from URL:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
```

Am I able to write a test method to the Controller's constructor?

Comment: check this out. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102740/how-to-write-test-class-for-standard-controller-along-with-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this doc on writing unit test for custom controller:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');